# Image of the upper half-plane under the mapping $\int_{0}^{z} (1-t^{2})^{- \frac{2}{3}}dt$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some difficulties about my homework, please help, thank you.
Find the image of the upper half-plane under the mapping $$\int_{0}^{z}\frac{dt}{(1-t^{2})^{\frac23}}$$

Comment: How the integral is defined if $z$ is a real number greater than one? It looks to me that such a function is defined only on the unit disk , and has two simple poles at $z=\pm 1$.

Comment: Have you learned about Schwarz-Christoffel mappings?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Especially in a problem about conformal mapping I'd take "upper half plane" to mean the _open_ upper half plane. The notation presumably refers to the integral over a path from $0$ to $z$ in the upper half plane. Then yes, the function blows up as $z$ tends to $\pm1$ _from_ within the upper half plane. It's not actually a pole at $1$, though: A pole is an isolated singularity, and the function can't be defined to be holomorphic in $0<|z-1|<r$. (Makes a difference: For example a function has a residue at a pole, while this function doesn't even have a Laurent series about $1$.)

Comment: No, I have not learned about Schwarz-Christoffel mappings, My teacher just showed us an example of $\int_{0}^{z}\frac{dt}{(1-t^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

Comment: And it is open upper half plane.